# Issues accessing api.twitter.com with Tweepy from behind a proxy

Tags: python, twitter, proxy, tweepy

I am a pretty novice (read self-taught) python user and I am having trouble figuring out the proxy functionality of tweepy.api(). Can someone please provide guidance or an example on how to best utilize this?

In this situation, we have a firewall up where our proxy uses a /tw/twapi as an alias to api.twitter.com. Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Tweepy doesn't provide proxy support.

But their are many of its forks which have proxy support.

1. https://github.com/crimsonredmk/tweepy/
2. https://bitbucket.org/sakito/tweepy

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The documentation at www.tweepy.org says it does.  Odd.

Comment: Have you tried using one these which I suggested. They have the same interface as tweepy.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working within a strict system within my firm where I cannot easily bring forks in so I have been unable to check them.